# Websphere 8.0 with myfaces 2.0 - slow RENDER_RESPONSE phase

Tags: jsf-2

I've finally completed converting of all jsp apps on my company's web site into jsf apps.  Everything works well excepts performance.  Prior to converting to jsf, almost all the jsp apps on the site were running under a sub-second response time.  After I converted them to jsf, almost all of them are running under response time of 7 to 10 seconds.  I added a phase listeners to the faces-config.xml.  Below is what I see.  The RENDER_REPONSE phase is taking up most of the response time.  Is this normal?  From sub-second to 7-10 seconds response time is significant and I can't image it being ok for others that doing this same type of conversion.

```
[3/23/15 11:24:31:631 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015
[3/23/15 11:24:31:631 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015.  Total Seconds = 0
[3/23/15 11:24:31:631 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015
[3/23/15 11:24:31:631 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015.  Total Seconds = 0
[3/23/15 11:24:31:632 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015
[3/23/15 11:24:31:632 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015.  Total Seconds = 0
[3/23/15 11:24:31:632 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015
[3/23/15 11:24:31:633 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015.  Total Seconds = 0
[3/23/15 11:24:31:633 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015
[3/23/15 11:24:31:633 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015.  Total Seconds = 0
[3/23/15 11:24:31:633 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:31 CDT 2015
[3/23/15 11:24:39:675 CDT] 00000074 SystemOut     O END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6).  Time = Mon Mar 23 11:24:39 CDT 2015.  Total Seconds = 8
```

Comment: Many things happen during render response. What exactly is consuming most time? We can't see that based on the information provided so far.

Comment: @BalusC:  After adding some logging, I think I've found the problem. My log shows that right after the START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE, there is a 4 secs delay before it gets to my first ManageBean method.  It appears to be caused by javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD is being set to 0.  After I changed this setting in web.xml to -1, the response time is greatly increased.